# Laravel 5.4 queue:restart on windows?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am learning laravel 5.4 "queues" chapter. I have a problem about `queue:restart` command. Because when I test it on my windows 10 platform, I found this command seems just kill queue worker, but not restart worker. So I wonder whether this command does not work on windows or this command is just kill worker but not restart worker? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue:restart` command never actually restarts a worker, it just tells it to shutdown. It is supposed to be combined with a process manager like supervisor that will restart the process when it quits. This also happens when `queue:work` hits the configured memory limits.

> To keep the queue:work process running permanently in the background, you should use a process monitor such as Supervisor to ensure that the queue worker does not stop running.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: Thanks for your answer.